# Spring Boot - Jwts.builder Cannot resolve method 'signWith()’

Tags: java, spring, maven, jwt

I’ve been following [this spring boot + angular tutorial on YouTube](https://youtu.be/DKlTBBuc32c?t=2545) that uses spring security and JSON web tokens (JWT) for authenticating a user. However I’ve came to a point in the video where I have an error in my jwtUtil2 class. For some reason whenever I try to run my spring application  I get this error:

```
Error:(41, 17) java: no suitable method found for signWith(java.security.PrivateKey)
    method io.jsonwebtoken.JwtBuilder.signWith(io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureAlgorithm,byte[]) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method io.jsonwebtoken.JwtBuilder.signWith(io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureAlgorithm,java.lang.String) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method io.jsonwebtoken.JwtBuilder.signWith(io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureAlgorithm,java.security.Key) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
```

Also If I look at the jwtUtil2 class it has a red line underneath the parameter that is supplied to the Jwts.builder().signWith() method on line 41. If I hover over the error it says: Cannot resolve method 'signWith(java.security.PrivateKey)'.

```
@Service
public class JwtUtilTwo
{
    private KeyStore keyStore;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        try
        {
            keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
            InputStream resourceAsStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/springblog.jks");
            keyStore.load(resourceAsStream, "secret".toCharArray());
        }
        catch (KeyStoreException | CertificateException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | IOException e)
        {
            throw new SpringRubbishRewardsException("Exception occurred while loading keystore");
        }
    }

    public String generateToken(Authentication authentication) {
        User principal = (User) authentication.getPrincipal();
        return Jwts.builder()
                .setSubject(principal.getUsername())
                .signWith(getPrivateKey()) //ERROR HERE
                .compact();
    }

    private PrivateKey getPrivateKey()
    {
        try
        {
            return (PrivateKey) keyStore.getKey("springblog", "secret".toCharArray());
        }
        catch (KeyStoreException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | UnrecoverableKeyException e)
        {
            throw new SpringRubbishRewardsException("Exception occurred while retrieving public key from keystore");
        }
    }
}
```

Now I have actually found a way to fix the error, by changing the Maven dependencies in the pom file. I looked at the YouTube tutorial’s GitHub repository for the video and copied the following JWT dependencies and commented out my original JWT dependency:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>rubbish-rewards</groupId>
    <artifactId>rubbish-rewards-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!--<dependency> MY ORIGINAL JWT DEPENDENCY
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>-->

        <!--NEW JWT DEPENDENCIES FROM THE TUTORIALS GITHUB REPOSITORY -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.10.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <version>0.10.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <version>0.10.5</version>
        </dependency>

       <!--==================================================-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Although that fixes the first issue, it introduces a new issue when I try to run my application. This time it has an error that reads:

```
2020-07-14 11:52:35.833  WARN 14616 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'authenticateController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'authenticateService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'authenticateService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'jwtUtil2'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jwtUtilTwo': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is rubbishrewards.exceptions.SpringRubbishRewardsException: Exception occurred while loading keystore
```

I would post the code to my authenticationController and AuthenticationService classes but I feel as though it will make this question too cluttered. So instead [here’s a link to my applications GitHub repository](https://github.com/SneakyShrike/rubbish-rewards-api).

[Here is a link to the YouTube tutorial (timestamped)](https://youtu.be/DKlTBBuc32c?t=2545) and [a link to the videos accompanying GitHub repository](https://github.com/SaiUpadhyayula/spring-reddit-clone).

I’m new to spring so I have no clue what's going on. If anyone could help I’d appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

this could be useful for you..

```
    SecretKeySpec secret_key = new SecretKeySpec(env.getProperty("token.secret").getBytes("UTF-8"), "HmacSHA256");
    
    
    String token=Jwts.builder().setSubject(userdetails.getUserid())
    .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()+Long.parseLong(env.getProperty("token.expiration_time"))))
    .signWith(secret_key)
    .compact();
    
     
    res.addHeader("token", token);
    res.addHeader("userid", userdetails.getUserid());
```

also depending on what dependencies you already have in your pom.xml, you might also need to add the following dependencies: jjwt-impl, jjwt-jackson.